# Error: Could not find or load main class in module Programa_leitura

Tags: java

Eu estou com esse erro a hora que tento rodar minha aplicação, alguém sabe me ajudar ? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O correto seria `main` e não `valor`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //restante omitido.
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado me ajudo, kkkkkkk eu sou meio que iniciante e não sabia disso, mas obrigado mesmo ajudo muito :)

Comment: @Lopes555, no início é assim mesmo. Ah... não esquece de marcar como resposta para fechar este tópico. Bons estudos. (:

Comment: Como faz pra ''marcar como resposta'' ?

Comment: Confere aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta